# why can not add float Calculator use bison and flex

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to implement a simple calculator (for operations +-*/) with unsigned floating point and integer numbers. Firstly, I use flex to match lexical analysis and bison to match arithmetic expressions. My Compiler input eg：

```
0.5*0.5
>>0.000000
```

If I try use Int calculator. it can successfully.

the test.l

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
void yyerror(char *);
%}
NUM [1-9]+[0-9]*|0
FNUM [0-9]+\.[0-9]+
%%


{FNUM}                      sscanf(yytext,"%f",&yylval.dnum); return FNUM;
"+"                         return ADD;
"-"                         return SUB;
"*"                         return MUL;
"/"                         return DIV;
\n                          return CR;
[ \t]+                     /* ignore whitespace */;
.
%%
```

test.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *);
%}

%union{
  int inum;
  double dnum;
}
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV CR
//%token <inum> NUM
%type  <dnum> expression term single
%token <dnum> FNUM

%%
       line_list: line
                | line_list line
                ;
                
           line : expression CR  {printf(">>%f\n",$1);}

      expression: term 
                | expression ADD term   {$$=$1+$3;}
                | expression SUB term   {$$=$1-$3;}
                ;

            term: single
                | term MUL single       {$$=$1*$3;}
                | term DIV single       {$$=$1/$3;}
                ;
                
          //single: NUM;
          single:FNUM
                ;
                               
%%
void yyerror(char *str){
    fprintf(stderr,"error:%s\n",str);
}

int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    yyparse();
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%f"` expects a pointer to float, not double. You should be getting a compiler warning about that.

Comment: I am so stupid, thank you for point to error.